# Enviar variable entre dos archivos php

Tags: php, mysql, php5

Buenas

Tengo una página donde muestro una tabla sql. Y quiero que si el usuario pulsa en un título se muestre solo la información de un fila.

Lo estoy intentado hacer así, news.php:

```
<form action="new.php" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                            <h1><a type="submit" href="new.php">
                        <?php 
                            echo $row['name']; 
                        ?>
                            </a></h1>
                        </form>
```

Y en new.php recibo la información:

```
$variable1=($_POST['id']);
```

Da este error:

```
Undefined index: id
```

No lo reconoce y no se por que. Gracias

Todo el codigo php para verlo mejor. news.php:

```
<?php
            include ('cfgdb.php');
            reset($db);
            try {
                $i=0;
                foreach($db->query("SELECT `id`,`name`,`description`,`autor`, `fecha`, `imgRuta`,`imgNom`,`show1`, url FROM `noticias`") as $row) {
                   //print_r($row);
                    if ($row['show1']){
                            //echo '<div class="curso '.$colors[rand(0,9)].'">';
                        ?>
                        <article class="blog wow fadeInUp">
                        <figure>
                        <?php
                        //}
                        //echo '<div class="row">';
                        echo '<img src="'.$row['imgRuta'].'" width="727" height="485"  alt="'.$row['name'].'">';
                        ?>
                        </figure>
                        <header>
                        <form action="new.php" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                            <h1><a type="submit" href="new.php">
                        <?php 
                            echo $row['name']; 
                        ?>
                            </a></h1>
                        </form>

                        <div class ="info">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i><a>
                        <?php 
                            echo $row['autor']; 
                        ?>
                        </a></span>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        <?php 
                            $date = date_create($row['fecha']);                                
                            echo date_format($date,'Y-m-d');
                        ?>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                        </header>
                        <p>
                            <?php 
                                echo '<p>'.$row['description'].'</p>'; 
                            ?>
                        </p>
                        </article>
                        <span class="line"></span>
                        <?php 
                        /*echo '<a data-remodal-target="'.$row['url'].'" class="btn btn-infoo" href="#'.$row['url'].'">';
                        echo '<i class="fa fa-info"></i> Más Info</a>';
                        echo '<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="'.$row['url'].'">';
                        echo '<h1>'.$row['name'].'</h1>';
                        echo $row['description'];
                        //echo '<br>&nbsp;<br>'.$row['description_hours'];
                        //echo '<b><br>Fecha de Comienzo: '.$row["DATE_FORMAT(`date_init`,GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR'))"];
                        //echo '<br>Fecha de Fin: '.$row["DATE_FORMAT(`date_end`,GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR'))"];
                        echo '<br/>&nbsp;<br><a class="remodal-confirm" href="#">Ok!</a></div></div>';*/
                    }
                }
                $db = null;

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
                die();
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas utilizando un link(alemento `a`) como si fuese un buton submit y esto no se puede ya que al dar click sobre el link solo te redireccionara a la url pero no enviara la información del formulario:

Cambia:

```
   <a type="submit" href="new.php"> <?php  echo $row['name'];  ?> </a>
```

Por

```
<input type="submit" value="<?php  echo $row['name'];  ?>" />
```